# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufe0e' in position 509: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

When I tried to add a excel to mysql database using pandas I'm facing this error and I cannot understand why this error is showing up even though the data is clean and every thing is in a string format. Here is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
my_conn = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://dbadmin:Nikhil0199@localhost/djangodatabase")
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("D:\\New Task\\django\\task\\airbnblistings.xlsx")
df.to_sql(con = my_conn, name = 'airbnblistings', if_exists = 'replace', index = True)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.